# Add a custom field value as a cart non taxable fee in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, fee

I have a custom field in checkout that adds a price to cart.

```
$woocommerce->cart->add_fee($price_info['label'], $fee, $taxable, $tax_class);
```

Everything works fine. But how do i make it non taxable ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make a fee non taxable you need to set the 3rd argument to false, so your code will be:

```
WC()->cart->add_fee( $price_info['label'], $fee );
```

The default value for the 3rd argument is `false`, so no taxable. See its source code:

```
/**
 * Add additional fee to the cart.
 *
 * @uses WC_Cart_Fees::add_fee
 * @param string $name      Unique name for the fee. Multiple fees of the same name cannot be added.
 * @param float  $amount    Fee amount (do not enter negative amounts).
 * @param bool   $taxable   Is the fee taxable? (default: false).
 * @param string $tax_class The tax class for the fee if taxable. A blank string is standard tax class. (default: '').
 */

public function add_fee( $name, $amount, $taxable = false, $tax_class = '' ) {
    $this->fees_api()->add_fee( array(
        'name'      => $name,
        'amount'    => (float) $amount,
        'taxable'   => $taxable,
        'tax_class' => $tax_class,
    ) );
}
```

> Now if you use **a negative fee** (so a cart discount), **it will be taxable** even if you set it to `false`.

Comment: i want to add fee to cart but fee should be displayed without tax and total should be with tax

Comment: @melvin So you should override woocommerce templates via your theme. The templates are `cart/cart-totals.php` and also `checkout/review-order.php`

Comment: is it possible without overriding but by using functions of woocommerce ?

Comment: @melvin I don't think so…