# WooCommerce add non-taxable fee and discount to cart calculates wrong tax amount

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a WooCommerce site where products may have a non-taxable deposit fee, may have a delivery fee ($7.50), and may have a discount. Without applying the *negative* fee (discount) the tax is calculated correctly. Once I add the negative fee, the tax includes the non-taxable deposit fee in its calculation. I read somewhere that negative fees are not recommended. I also [found this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48901869/add-a-custom-field-value-as-a-cart-non-taxable-fee-in-woocommerce?rq=1) but don't know if this applies here. Is there another way to accomplish this in the cart and also show in the orders, emails, etc.? FYI the tax rate is 15%. Here's the code I'm using:

```
function woocommerce_custom_fees( $cart ) {
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    // Loop through cart items
    foreach ( $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
        $item_data = $cart_item['data'];
        $deposit = $item_data->get_attribute('deposit');
        $delivery = $cart_item['delivery'];

        if ( $deposit ) {
            $total_deposit += $cart_item['quantity'] * $deposit;
        }

        if ( $delivery == 'deliver' ) {
            $total_delivery += $cart_item['quantity'] * 7.5;
        }
    }

    if ( $total_deposit > 0 ) {
        // non-taxable
        $cart->add_fee( 'Deposit', $total_deposit, FALSE );
    }

    if ( $total_delivery > 0 ) {
        // taxable
        $cart->add_fee( 'Delivery', $total_delivery, TRUE );
    }

    //  test $10 discount
    $cart->add_fee( 'Test discount', -10.00);
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees','woocommerce_custom_fees', 25, 1 );
```

[correct tax amount without negative fee](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OVJsq.png)

[incorrect tax amount with negative fee](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DdrbS.png)

UPDATE: I found this post [Apply a discount on the cart content total excluding taxes in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47802738/apply-a-discount-on-the-cart-content-total-excluding-taxes-in-woocommerce) which says that using a negative fee will cause the taxes to always get applied. Is there an alternative method to apply discounts in the cart other than to use negative fees or coupons?

Comment: Can anyone else offer any help? Maybe this won't work with multiple taxable and non-taxable fees. The only examples I've found include one fee. Is there another method instead of using a negative fee?

Answer (score 0):

```
function woocommerce_custom_fees( $cart ) {
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;


        // non-taxable
        $cart->add_fee( 'Deposit', 6, FALSE );



        // taxable
        $cart->add_fee( 'Delivery', 7, TRUE );


    //  test $10 discount
    //$cart->add_fee( 'Test discount', -10.00 , FALSE);
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees','woocommerce_custom_fees', 25, 1 );



add_filter( 'woocommerce_calculated_total', 'discounted_calculated_total', 10, 2 );
function discounted_calculated_total( $total, $cart ){

    $total = $total - 10;

    return $total;
}
```

Tried this way?

Comment: Yes, I did try that and it does not calculate properly...it simply subtracts 10 from the final total and it calculates the tax on the full product price, not the discounted product price. Nor does it display the discount in the summary of charges. Thanks though.  

Subtotal $13.15  
HST         $1.97  
Deposit $0.20  
Total $5.32